# Change a setting on CDN-hosted JS file without touching file

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I'm using the jump-forward plugin for mediaelements.js that hosted on CloudFlare.

I'm not familiar with JS so I'm wondering if it's possible to change the JS file without having to download the file and host it locally?

For example: the broswer loads this 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement-plugins/2.1.0/jump-forward/jump-forward.min.js' then either run a script to make a change on one line:

```
Object.assign(mejs.MepDefaults, {
/**
* @type {Number}
*/
jumpForwardInterval: 30,
/**
* @type {?String}
*/
jumpForwardText: null
});
```

I don't know if this is possible. I'm just looking for something to make a change to a remotely-hosted JS that's up-to-date instead of downloading the JS, make the change, and host it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Requestly extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa).

It provides a file hosting service that you can use to host your local files. What you need to do is

- Install Requestly extension from http://www.requestly.in
- Download your JS file on local machine
- Use Requestly Library service to host your file (http://www.requestly.in/library)
- Modify your content on library service
- Open http://www.requestly.in/rules
- Create a Replace rule to redirect the original JavaScript url to changed file url (Url obtained from library service)

[Replace Rule Documentation](http://www.requestly.in/content/documentation/replace-rule/)

Comment: Never heard of Requestly, will look into it. However, this is on a local environment. This doesn't work on a server level?

Comment: Yes it works only for your browser, mainly if you want to see how a change will look without modifying remote file. For server level you have to deploy updated file on server.